# Some statements are skipped in C program in particular cases

Tags: c, netbeans

I am working on a C application in NetBeans IDE,application is Basically a client-server model.I calculate some value based on data from Client,but  during a particular case the value calculation fails. Instead of returning value as 65536 I get the value as 256.

The following is the case:

```
int pckt_number = 0; //size of int is 4 bytes.

        pckt_number = 0 << 8 ; // 1

        pckt_number |= 1 << 8; //2

        pckt_number |= 0 << 8 ; //3

        pckt_number |= 0; //4
```

Here both 3rd and 4th  statements are skipped from execution,and the value is returned as 256 instead of 65536.for rest of the cases from 1 to 65535 correct value is calculated. please note int is of 4 bytes.

Comment: This code shall result in 256. Not 65536. Why did you expect 65536.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's see what happens:

```
int pckt_number = 0;     // 0
pckt_number |= 0 << 8;   // pckt_number = pckt_number | 0    --> still 0
pckt_number |= 1 << 8;   // pckt_number = pckt_number | 256  --> 256
pckt_number |= 0 << 8;   // pckt_number = pckt_number | 0    --> still 256
pckt_number |= 0;        // pckt_number = pckt_number | 0    --> still 256
```

The last two statements simply do nothing. They are not "skipped". The first line `pckt_number |= 0 << 8` does nothing either.

Comment: From client I am sending continuous packet number from 1 onwards until commanded to stop. like there can be packet number up-to 99999 or more. when packet number is 65536 I get packet number as 256 as my system halts as it is expecting packet number as 65536. How Can I solve my problem. Plz provide any Idea.

Comment: @Asusgates: I don't understand the comment, sorry. What is your problem? Can't you simply count, i.e. `0, 1, 2, 3 .. 99999`. What are you trying to achieve with the shifts?

Comment: From @aebudak's answer I see that you have 4 8-bit bytes and want to assemble those into a 32-bit (unsigned) integer. Why didn't you simply say so, instead of letting people guess?

Answer (score 2):

`pckt_number |= 0 << 8` is evaluated as `pckt_number |= (0 << 8)` which is `pckt_number |= 0`.

`x | 0` is `x` for *any* `x`. Hence `x |= 0` is a no-op.

So the statements that you've marked as `//3` and `//4` are no-ops.

Answer (score 1):

[Rudy Velthuis's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38566818/6573268) explains it perfectly. If I understand correctly what you are trying to do can be done like this.

```
int pckt_number = 0;     // 0
pckt_number |= 0 << 24;  // most significant byte,  
pckt_number |= 1 << 16;  // second most significant byte,
pckt_number |= 0 << 8;   // third most significant byte,
pckt_number |= 0;        // least significant byte,
```

Comment: I would understand if it were something like `pckt_number |= a shr 24;`, etc., but `0 << 24` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I never thought that 0s and 1s were constants. Because if they were `int pckt_number = 65536;` would be sufficient.